# How to remove the rotation of the player towards the second player?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

The player, when he receives damage, starts running faster and the running animation is connected, but if the player just stands up and is attacked, the player turns towards the second player who hits him and starts running on the spot. The question is, how to fix it?

The script below -

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.AI;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    const string IDLE = "m_idle_A";
    const string WALK = "m_run";
    const string DEATH = "m_death_A";

    // Your variables
    CustomAction input;
    NavMeshAgent agent;
    Animator animator;
    private Animator playerAnimator;

    [Header("Movement")]
    [SerializeField] ParticleSystem clickEffect;
    [SerializeField] LayerMask clickableLayers;

    [Header("Speed Boost")]
    [SerializeField] float speedBoost = 2.0f;
    [SerializeField] float maxBoostDuration = 7.0f;
    private float initialSpeed;
    private bool isBoosting;
    private float boostDuration;

    [Header("Health")]
    [SerializeField] int maxHealth = 2;
    private int currentHealth;
    [SerializeField] Text hpText;

    [Header("Fail Screen UI")]
    [SerializeField] RawImage FailImage;
    [SerializeField] Text YouDieAboutText;
    [SerializeField] Text YouDieText;
    [SerializeField] Text YouDieLVLAboutText;
    [SerializeField] Text YouDieLVLText;
    [SerializeField] Text DieScoreMoney;
    [SerializeField] Button MenuButton;

    [Header("Win Screen UI")]
    [SerializeField] RawImage WinImage;
    [SerializeField] Text YouWinAboutText;
    [SerializeField] Text YouWinText;
    [SerializeField] Text YouWinLVLAboutText;
    [SerializeField] Text YouWinLVLText;
    [SerializeField] Text WinScoreMoney;
    [SerializeField] Button MenuWinButton;

    [SerializeField] float lookRotationSpeed = 8.0f;

    private bool isRunning = false;

    void Awake()
    {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        playerAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();

        // Initialize custom actions
        input = new CustomAction();
        AssignInputs();
    }

    void AssignInputs()
    {
        // Assign handlers to actions
        input.Main.Move.performed += ctx => ClickToMove();
    }

    void ClickToMove()
    {
        // Handle mouse click movement
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit, 100, clickableLayers))
        {
            agent.destination = hit.point;

            // Play a click effect if available
            if (clickEffect != null)
            {
                Instantiate(clickEffect, hit.point + new Vector3(0, 0.1f, 0), clickEffect.transform.rotation);
            }
        }
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        input.Enable();
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        input.Disable();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        // Initial setup at the start of the game
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
        UpdateHPText();
        FailImage.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        MenuButton.gameObject.SetActive false);
        YouDieAboutText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        YouDieText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        YouDieText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        YouDieText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        DieScoreMoney.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        initialSpeed = agent.speed;
        isBoosting = false;
        boostDuration = 0f;

        // Generate random values for death score and level
        int randomDieScore = Random.Range(10, 15);
        DieScoreMoney.text = randomDieScore.ToString();

        int randomYouDieLVL = Random.Range(37, 53);
        YouDieLVLText.text = randomYouDieLVL.ToString();

        // Initial setup for win screen elements
        WinImage.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        MenuWinButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        YouWinAboutText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        YouWinText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        YouWinText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        YouWinText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        WinScoreMoney.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        // Generate random values for win score and level
        int randomWinScore = Random.Range(40, 75);
        WinScoreMoney.text = randomWinScore.ToString();

        int randomYouWinLVL = Random.Range(37, 53);
        YouWinLVLText.text = randomYouWinLVL.ToString();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Update character's facing and animations
        FaceTarget();
        SetAnimations();

        if (isRunning)
        {
            animator.Play(WALK);
        }

        if (isBoosting)
        {
            boostDuration -= Time.deltaTime;

            if (boostDuration <= 0f)
            {
                isBoosting = false;
                SetSpeed(initialSpeed);
            }
        }

        if (currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            // Play death animation if health reaches zero
            playerAnimator.Play(DEATH);
            this.enabled = false;
        }
    }

    void FaceTarget()
    {
        // Rotate the character to face the target
        Vector3 direction = agent.destination - transform.position;

        if (direction != Vector3.zero)
        {
            Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(direction.x, 0, direction.z));
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * lookRotationSpeed);
        }
    }

    void SetAnimations()
    {
        // Control movement animations
        if (agent.velocity == Vector3.zero)
        {
            animator.Play(IDLE);
            isRunning = false;
        }
        else
        {
            isRunning = true;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Hunter"))
        {
            if (currentHealth > 0)
            {
                currentHealth--;
                UpdateHPText();
                ApplySpeedBoost();
            }

            if (currentHealth == 0)
            {
                // If health is zero, start a coroutine to show the fail screen objects after a delay
                StartCoroutine(ShowObjectsAfterDelay(2f));
            }
        }

        if (other.CompareTag("WinLine"))
        {
            // If the character reaches the win point, display the win screen and disable this script
            WinImage.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            MenuWinButton.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            YouWinAboutText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            YouWinText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            YouWinText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            YouWinText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            WinScoreMoney.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            this.enabled = false;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ShowObjectsAfterDelay(float delay)
    {
        // Coroutine to delay the appearance of objects on the fail screen
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

        FailImage.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        MenuButton.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        YouDieAboutText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        YouDieText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        YouDieLVLAboutText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        YouDieLVLText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        DieScoreMoney.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void ApplySpeedBoost()
    {
        // Apply speed boost
        isBoosting = true;
        boostDuration = maxBoostDuration;
        SetSpeed(initialSpeed + speedBoost);
    }

    private void SetSpeed(float speed)
    {
        agent.speed = speed;
    }

    private void UpdateHPText()
    {
        // Update the health level text
        hpText.text = "HP: " + currentHealth;
    }
}
```

I tried to fix it through ChatGPT but nothing worked(

Comment: Your `Update` method calls `FaceTarget();` as it's first action. Perhaps you need to set a variable for when your character is just standing up so that you can skip the call to `FaceTarget()` in the `Update` method. *You are also proving why ChatGPT and A.I. is not capable of replacing a human when working in the software world.*

Comment: if the FaceTarget() method rotates the character to face a target (like an enemy or destination), you might want to skip this rotation when the character is just standing up and has no target to face.

To achieve this, you can introduce a boolean variable, say isStandingUp, to track when the player is standing up.